# OpenLayers FramedCloud has transparent background

Tags: openlayers-2, popup

I am creating a FrameCloud popup instance and adding to the map using the following code:

```
  var popup = new OpenLayers.Popup.FramedCloud("popup",
                point,
                null,
                '<div> test context </div>',   
                null, true);

            map.addPopup(popup);
```

Popup is displayed at the correct location but with a transparent background probably because I am using a local copy of OpenLayers.js instead of the public version.  For local deployment, where do I put the resources found under the img folder required by OpenLayers?

Answer (score 1):

Answer lies in readme.md available as part of the OpenLayer download package.  Local deployment requires the theme and img directories be deployed in same directory as OpenLayers.js.  Not really what I want to do but that was the missing link.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to overwrite image path, you can use this code with adding it to begining of your script.

```
OpenLayers.ImgPath = "img/";
```

i hope it helps you...